# Conditional independence under joint random variables

Tags: probability

Consider random variables $X,Y,A,B$ such that $X$ is independent of $Y$ given $A$, and $X$ is independent of $Y$ given $B$. Is $X$ is independent of $Y$ given $A,B$. I tried proving it but I think that it does not hold. I am unable to construct a counter-example however.

Comment: Union? $X$ independent of $Y$ given $A, B$ would translate to $A$ _intersection_ $B$, will it not? (Which should hold)

Comment: Edited! thanks.

Comment: OK, I haven't solved it, but at a glance it looks like it should hold. If $X$ is conditionally independent of $Y$ for _all_ values of $A$, then it should be conditionally independent of $Y$ given $A \cap B$.

Comment: I think that the interpretation using events is confusing to me. Consider them as random variables. Would it hold now?

Comment: Random Variables would still function over an event space, though.

Comment: True! Can you write the formal proof that would imply the third from the first two? I am unable to show this. I get the intuition though.

Comment: I would have to think about the proof. It's just my instinct right now.